# Modifying the tag <A> via jQuery each loop

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to modify a series of tag  in a string that is taken from a textarea (TinyMCE). 
I'd like to add data-toggle, data-hover and a class (only if there is a specific word in a the href attribute)

```
var elements = tinyMCE.get('text').getContent(); //retrieve the content from textarea
var results = [];
var links = [];
$(elements).html(elements).find("a").each(function(l) {
     $(this).attr("data-toggle", "popover");
     $(this).attr("data-trigger", "hover");
     $(this).addClass("classLink");

     results.push($(this).attr('href'));
     str = $(this).attr('data-toggle') + "--" + $(this).attr('data-trigger') + "---" + $(this).attr('class');
     links.push(str);

 });
 console.log(results);
 console.log(links);
```

Now the two arrays printed in the console show the right content. The problem is that I'd like to update the string `elements` and update the content in the textarea.

And after many attempt by using the `alert()` function nothing works. 
Any idea? 
Thanks a lot

Comment: What textarea, is that behind the `.get('text')`? Sounds like you need to select it and set its `value` (or maybe there's a special `tinyMCE` for that)

Comment: I can use `tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(elements);` but by simply using `alert(elements)` I can see that the elements the tag A do not changed after the each loop (with the arrays displaying the right data)

Comment: $this.data('toggle', ...
You'd probably get better help with a jsFiddle b.t.w.

Comment: No the setting of the attributes data is correct. The problem is that it seems that it does not affect the string `elements`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting a string, creating html elements from it, modifying those elements, but you're not pushing the elements back into the string

```
var elements = tinymce.activeEditor.getContent()

var $elements = $('<div>' + elements + '</div>');
$elements.find("a").each(function() {
     $(this).addClass("classLink");
     });

elements = $elements.html();
tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(elements)
alert(elements)
```

I just tried this via http://fiddle.tinymce.com/ and it seems to work, the content in tinymce is updated

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/R2gaab

Comment: I noticed a small bug, if the content that I retrieve from tinyMCE has more than one `<p>` the result seems to be truncated where the first `<p>` ends.

Comment: Wrapping the contents in a div seems to fix that, I've updated the example above